# How to locate FCC ID of a bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, fcc

I'm trying to [find](https://fccid.io) the FCC ID for a super common bluetooth trigger, the one used on all the selfie sticks.

I went through each manufacturer name I saw on Alibaba and input their company names into FCC site, but none of them show this specific [product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Kc0.jpg).

How is it possible that these companies manufacture this trigger and send it to US without the FCC certification? The devices show the FCC logo.

What else can I do to locate it? I tried opening the devices from 2 different manufacturers, but can't find it.

It is possible that they all ripped off some patent and all use 1 FCC ID that belonged to the original manufacturer of the device? Hence, the reason why when I search for individual manufacturers I can't find FCC application for that device.

Comment: Your link for "product" is no good.  The device itself is supposed to display the FCC ID, usually on the top of the metal module.  It is sometimes hard to see (you often have to tilt the module to see it)., so unless you have the physical product you may miss it.

Comment: @tcrosley thank you so much for the reply, here's the picture of the PCB, I just opened it up. Are any of the things in it the FCC id? http://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Kc0.jpg

Comment: No. there are no FCC IDs on the circuit board. It should be clearly marked as an FCC ID and is usually on the exterior part number manufacturer label.